# Row of grid columns not showing as columns

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm having an issue with one row of my CSS Grid-formatted page not placing the three images in its designated columns.

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<html>
  <title></title>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div class="Main">
        <div class="Header Box">
          <div id="One"> 
            <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/2gy4am3oov/Satellite_over_earth_2.jpg" width="200px" height="126px"/>
          </div>
          <div id="Two"><p>UNIVERSIAL</p><p>TECHNOLOGIES</p>     
          </div>
          <div id="Three"> Blah blah blah 
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class = "Second Row">
          <div>
          Technology you can trust

  Ethersonic Technologies has been servicing Chicago and the surrounding suburbs since April 2008. We are a Certified (VOSB) Veteran Owned Small Business with the Federal Government and a member of the BB​B (Better Business Bureau) with an A+ rating.

  Ethersonic specializes in Computer  diagnosis and repair, Security Camera Installation and repair and Network Installation and Repair  
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/284vrnvfsv/BBB_and_VOSB_Logos.jpg" width="300" height="187"/>
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="Third Row">
          <div>
        <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/1dv3jss5yn/asus-reveals-the-rog-g11-gaming-desktop-491165-2.jpg" width="300" height="203"
          </div>
          <div>
          <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/1dv3jss5yn/asus-reveals-the-rog-g11-gaming-desktop-491165-2.jpg" width="300" height="203"
          </div>
          <div>
          <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/1dv3jss5yn/asus-reveals-the-rog-g11-gaming-desktop-491165-2.jpg" width="300" height="203"
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>       
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is with the row entitled **Third Row**. Here:

```
<div class="Third Row">
```

And here is my CSS code:

```css
.Main{
  background-color: yellow;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:(3, 1fr);
}

.Header.Box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  background-color: red;
  grid-gap: 0;
}

#One, #Two, #Three {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;  
}

.Second.Row{
  display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.Third.Row{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  background-color: green;
}
```

The problem lies with the CSS rule entitled **Third Row**

```css
.Third.Row{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  background-color: green;
}
```

Both HTML-wise and CSS-wise, **Third Row**, is formatted the same as **Second Row**, but for some reason the CSS rule for **Third Row** doesn't work as it does for **Second Row**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some issues with your html. You do not close the `img` tags.
Doing that your layout for the third row will work as you have defined it (with three columns)

```
<div class="Third Row">
  <div>
    <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/1dv3jss5yn/asus-reveals-the-rog-g11-gaming-desktop-491165-2.jpg" width="300" height="203" /> <!-- add tag closing -->
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/1dv3jss5yn/asus-reveals-the-rog-g11-gaming-desktop-491165-2.jpg" width="300" height="203" /> <!-- add tag closing -->
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/1dv3jss5yn/asus-reveals-the-rog-g11-gaming-desktop-491165-2.jpg" width="300" height="203" /> <!-- add tag closing -->
  </div>
```

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eeOWKJ)

Comment: thanks soooo much! I gues a good practice is to always close the images tags ahead of time hahaha :D